# possible to set google chrome policies on non-managed computer

Tags: linux, google-chrome

I have seen a fair number of sites that list the ability to control the behavior of chrome through setting policies.  For example you can disable multiple users, disable guest user, disable incognito mode, etc.  (Yes this is for my kid to use in online classes.)

However, most everything I see pertains to using enterprise/school Google accounts where administrators can set policies and push them to managed computers.

I get the sense that setting such a policy might be possible by using a .json file placed in the right location. Been a bear trying to figure that out and the right format to, for example just disable the guest account and incognito mode.

Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 3):

Placing this `policies.json` file in the directory `/etc/opt/chrome/policies/managed` directory will disable adding additional chrome accounts, disable the guest account, and disable incognito mode on the entire device.

```
{
        "BrowserGuestModeEnabled": false,
        "BrowserAddPersonEnabled": false,
        "IncognitoModeAvailability": 1
}
```

more information about setting this up can be found here:

https://www.chromium.org/administrators/linux-quick-start

and the full list of policies can be browsed and searched here:

https://cloud.google.com/docs/chrome-enterprise/policies/